# Bluetooth 4.0 Low Energy support on Sony Xperia Z5 or Z5 Compact

Tags: bluetooth-le

Could anyone please tell me if the Sony Xperia Z5 (or Z5 Compact) supports the Bluetooth 4.0 Low Energy profiles? I can't find any specification where this information is available (on gsmarena.com the specification does not explicitly state LE as for other phones - e.g. Samsung Galaxy S6 or even Sony Xperia Z3 Compact). Maybe somebody already tested the device with a BLE device?!

Thank you in advance!
MDV

Comment: If anyone needs this information, the Sony Xperia Z5 supports the Bluetooth 4.0 Low Energy profiles. I could test the device at a local reseller and it successfully recognized a BLE tag.

Answer (score 1):

The Xperia z5 does support BLE, however with Android 5.1 and 6.0 I have been having enormous issues with it. Bluetooth regular profiles have been fine for me (audio mostly) but other people are seeing issues with connecting to car kits and the like.

I have an Xperia Z5 Compact, unlocked and unmodified. I have trouble connecting to my Pebble Time watch (basically will not work at all), TrackR tags keep losing their connection and my Jawbone UP3 frequently is disconnected. As I say though audio to my Bluetooth headphones, portable speaker and home Amplifier are all fine.

I do believe the issue is with the phone, and hope very much for a swift update to solve this because it is very annoying.